# Prune origin branches that do not exist on upstream anymore

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fork

These branches are on **upstream**

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/next
  remotes/origin/translation
  remotes/origin/v1.0.1
  remotes/origin/videoConverter
```

and these are branches on **my fork**

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/beta
  remotes/origin/dashboardNewContent
  remotes/origin/externalUrl
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/next
  remotes/origin/rc
  remotes/origin/rc-0.3.0
  remotes/origin/release-candidate
  remotes/origin/streama-node
  remotes/origin/translation
  remotes/origin/v1.0.0
  remotes/origin/videoConverter
  remotes/upstream/gh-pages
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/next
  remotes/upstream/translation
  remotes/upstream/v1.0.1
  remotes/upstream/videoConverter
```

The upstream repo has been updated since I forked it. I can't find a way to remove the branches from my fork that no longer exist on upstream. [This GitHub tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) shows how to sync commit history.

Is there a straightforward solution to this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A trick is to replace the `origin` within your local repo (which references your fork) with the `upstream` url:

```
git remote rename origin ori
git remote add origin $(git remote get-url upstream)
```

Then a single command `git fetch --prune` will remove all the obsolete remote tracking branches locally (the `remotes/origin/xxx` which are not in `upstream`, temporarily referenced by '`origin`')

Finally, you can, for each `remotes/ori/xxx` branches, check if `remotes/origin/xxx` exist. If not: `git push --delete ori xxx`.

Something like: (in bash)

```
for f in $(git for-each-ref refs/remotes/ori --format '%(refname:short)' |
       sed 's,ori/,,') do;
   git rev-parse -q --verify refs/remotes/origin/$f >/dev/null || 
      git push --delete ori ${f}
done
```

That script can be put in a `git-cleanup` (or any `git-xxx` name), and called with `git cleanup` (or `git xxx`). That way, it runs in its own bash, even on Windows.

To finish:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote rename ori origin
```

Comment: Nice, but to make the script reliable in case of future changes (Git's ref name code has been converting to pluggable back-ends), replace the `find .git` with `git for-each-ref` which will unfortunately require using `sed` or some such to edit out the remote's name.

Comment: Done, but I don't have a suitable repo for testing, so I tested individual parts individually.  Also I don't use Wndows, does the `> /dev/null` work right there?  (One would hope WIndows bash simulates /dev/null ... :-) )

Comment: Thank you! On Windows, it is nul. I will review your edit tomorrow. I am on my phone, in bed, about to sleep.